# Proving by induction of binary number.

Tags: induction, binary

If n is binary represented natural number, P(n) for some predicate P.

This is just a sample question I made.

Base case) Let n = 0.
This is divisible by 2

Induction step) Let n = k is a binary represented natural number such that P(n) is true.

In this case, what should I prove?
I found that if k is binary number, 2k and 2k+1 are binary number and they can cover all the binary numbers.

I think if I prove n+1 = 2k or 2k+1 is true for P, I can prove P(n+1) is true by induction.
But I'm not sure how can I justify n+1 is 2k or 2k+1.

Comment: "For any integer $n$, either $n$ has a certain property, or it doesn't" is not something you need induction to prove.

Comment: Sorry I made up question. The main question is if n is binary number then what is n+1

Comment: $n+1$ will also a binary number. And it will also be either even or odd, just like $n$ is.

Comment: I changed question

Comment: What I want to know is how can I justify n+1 is 2k or 2k+1.

Comment: A "binary" number is just a number. "Binary" is a means of writing out a name for the number. It is not a condition on numbers or a different type of number. Every real number has a binary form (a few have two binary forms, just like a few numbers have two decimal forms). Induction is about natural numbers, not how they are written down.